Neovim akinsho/bufferline plugin tabs not appearing
I've added the following to my plugins.lua file but I'm still not seeing tabs at the top of my screen when I have a buffer open in neovim. Currently running neovim in wsl2 windows terminal. What am I missing to get the bufferline plugin working correctly.
use {
  'akinsho/bufferline.nvim', 
  tag = "*", 
  requires = 'nvim-tree/nvim-web-devicons'
}


Are you calling require("bufferline").setup({}) ?

I was not thank you!

I was missing the following
use {
  'akinsho/bufferline.nvim', 
  tag = "*", 
  requires = 'nvim-tree/nvim-web-devicons',
  config = function()
    require("bufferline").setup({})
  end,
}

